# Flash suddenly no longer working in FF and Chromium - ... properties-gtk installed

Tags: firefox, flash, chromium

For some obscure reason flash has stopped working on my Ubuntu 14.04 a few days ago - in Firefox and Chrome, both are the latest versions.

I have uninstalled flash and re-installed from the Adobe website. No error message whatsoever, however, it is not working.

The `adobe-flash-properties-gtk` is installed, the latest version.

Any idea of how to get this fixed?

Comment: No need to install from the Adobe website. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html

Comment: How did you test flash and what makes you feel it is not working ?

Comment: Hi! Because Flash simply is no longer working. No Flash element shows up.